# How to placed a hardware to take pictures 360 degrees around a specific item

Tags: ios, image, graphics, computer-vision, 360-degrees

How to placed a hardware to take pictures 360 degrees around a specific item, manually controlled to start and finish. let's say it takes a picture in every 15 secs to get a total of 10-15 pictures which give us details of on each angle.

we need to combine all these pictures to get a 3D image. by turning this picture, either left to right or the other way around, it shows details all around the product base on these 10-15 pictures.
Please help...

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is out of the scope of pure iOS, except the fact that you are using camera. You need some deep understanding on computer vision to achieve that, as it's not as simple as clip the image, but also involves perspective view, etc.

Comment: i will use camera to click multiple image, now the problem is that how to make 3d image from multiple image?

Comment: see things like [AutoStitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoStitch) it create list of feature points (SIFT/SURF) for each image and match similar parts of image by RANSAC analysis ... that will obtain the join points coordinates from that is transformation matix per image formed and used to join all images together. (lot of DIP/CV/3Dgfx/math behind these few lines). Far simpler is to place your object on rotating plate and make images from tripod ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply Spektre, but is it possible in iOS programatically?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve exists here: https://photosynth.net/preview/view/75f3785a-9318-4a8b-b59a-49a807ee78fe (and it is a lot of work)

Comment: @ios add `@nick`  to comment specific user ... the site will send notification to him so s(he) knows someone is commenting to/him. If you got pixel access to the source image and have standard programing language (does not matter which) and platform with ALU and enough memory then yes this is doable. but as Rosa Gronchi mentioned it is a lot of work